# How to draw a draggable widget in HTML , preferably using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want an HTML div that would be free floating . Can be dragged and positioned any where irrespective of other elements. The element may block the view of elements below , that is no problem. Minimizing capability would be nice too. Is there any library for this.

Google search results in items that can be dragged from one position and put inside another. Couldn't find any free floating library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice directive, that you can use.
Its GitHub Link is... [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop).
Demo Can be found [here](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/#%2F)

Sample Code:

**HTML DOM:**

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" ng-hide="!list1.title">{{list1.title}}</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-droppable style='height:50px;'>
  <div class="btn btn-success" data-drag="false" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-draggable ng-hide="!list2.title">{{list2.title}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
App.controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list1 = {title: 'AngularJS - Drag Me'};
  $scope.list2 = {};
});
```

Comment: Its not actually free draggable to anywhere ...  You have to put it in the box.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `draggable` attribute and some logic in javascript..
(I have used js not angularjs so may be this won't be your answer)
code will be like

```js
function drag_start(event) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY) + ',' + event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));
}

function drag_over(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function drop(event) {
  var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
  var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
  dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
  dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
for (var i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
  dm[i].addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
}

body,
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div draggable="true" class="dragme" data-item="0">Drag me</div>
```

Comment: If you are referencing jquery already, why not simply call $(".dragme").draggable();? That achieves what the poster asked for. That or $(".dragme").dialog({ modal: false, autoOpen: true });. You did add the event handlers as well which is a bonus but wasn't asked for, so kudos :-). So yes, is the answer, there are libraries for this. Kendo and/or jquery to name two of many.

Comment: Yeah I thought about `draggable()` and `droppable()` but its drag to specified area I think and OP want to drag anywhere..That's why I attached event..Am I correct about that?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has a simple `draggable` option, take a look at it: 
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default

Also to have the div free floating just set it:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is not necessarily free floating; I believe you mean position: fixed. Or is it that I am missing something here? Absolute position should never be handled at the root HTML level; it should always have a container to keep the contents in the desired place.

Comment: i have used absolute at the root many times and never encountered a problem , was it wrong of me to do so? also, position fixed is effected by the page scroll so it is not totally 'free'.